# flume loss data when collect online data to hdfs

Tags: hadoop, flume-ng

I used **flume-ng 1.5** version to collect logs.

There are two agents in the data flow and they are on two hosts, respectively.

And the data is sended **from agent1 to agent2.**

The agents's component is as follows:

> agent1: spooling dir source --> file channel --> avro sink
>
> agent2: avro source --> file channel --> hdfs sink

**But it seems to loss data about 1/1000 percentage of million data.**
To solve problem I tried these steps:

1. look up agents log:  cannot find any error or exception.
2. look up agents monitor metrics: the events number that put and take from channel always equals
3. statistic the data number by hive query and hdfs file use shell, respectively: the two number is equal and less than the online data number

agent1's configuration:

```
#agent
agent1.sources = src_spooldir
agent1.channels = chan_file
agent1.sinks = sink_avro

#source
agent1.sources.src_spooldir.type = spooldir
agent1.sources.src_spooldir.spoolDir = /data/logs/flume-spooldir
agent1.sources.src_spooldir.interceptors=i1

#interceptors
agent1.sources.src_spooldir.interceptors.i1.type=regex_extractor
agent1.sources.src_spooldir.interceptors.i1.regex=(\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}).*
agent1.sources.src_spooldir.interceptors.i1.serializers=s1
agent1.sources.src_spooldir.interceptors.i1.serializers.s1.name=dt

#sink
agent1.sinks.sink_avro.type = avro
agent1.sinks.sink_avro.hostname = 10.235.2.212
agent1.sinks.sink_avro.port = 9910

#channel
agent1.channels.chan_file.type = file
agent1.channels.chan_file.checkpointDir = /data/flume/agent1/checkpoint
agent1.channels.chan_file.dataDirs = /data/flume/agent1/data

agent1.sources.src_spooldir.channels = chan_file
agent1.sinks.sink_avro.channel = chan_file
```

agent2's configuration

```
# agent 
agent2.sources  = source1
agent2.channels = channel1 
agent2.sinks    = sink1 

# source
agent2.sources.source1.type     = avro
agent2.sources.source1.bind     = 10.235.2.212
agent2.sources.source1.port     = 9910

# sink
agent2.sinks.sink1.type= hdfs
agent2.sinks.sink1.hdfs.fileType = DataStream
agent2.sinks.sink1.hdfs.filePrefix = log
agent2.sinks.sink1.hdfs.path = hdfs://hnd.hadoop.jsh:8020/data/%{dt}
agent2.sinks.sink1.hdfs.rollInterval = 600
agent2.sinks.sink1.hdfs.rollSize = 0
agent2.sinks.sink1.hdfs.rollCount = 0
agent2.sinks.sink1.hdfs.idleTimeout = 300
agent2.sinks.sink1.hdfs.round = true
agent2.sinks.sink1.hdfs.roundValue = 10
agent2.sinks.sink1.hdfs.roundUnit = minute

# channel
agent2.channels.channel1.type   = file
agent2.channels.channel1.checkpointDir = /data/flume/agent2/checkpoint
agent2.channels.channel1.dataDirs = /data/flume/agent2/data

agent2.sinks.sink1.channel      = channel1
agent2.sources.source1.channels = channel1
```

Any suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

there is a bug in file line deseriazer when encounter some specific character of utf which point is between U+10000 and U+10FFFF, they represent in utf16 by two 16-bit code unit called surrogate pairs.